# How to activate external beta testing in ITunes Connect for a new version after previous beta review approved?

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

- I submitted a new build from Xcode.
- I have a pre-released build on Itunes Connect.
- I filled in all information (by clicking on the build
  version) about this pre-version.
- I added external users (They have
  "Added" status)

But when I turn on beta test flights, external users stay at inactive status !
For a previous version, it proposed me a "send for app review" instead which was successful, but now I cannot use external test flight ...
I already read the apple documentation several times ... Is somebody also facing this issue ? Did I miss something ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: Also asked on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903954/external-testers-in-itunes-connect-always-remains-inactive-when-having-testfl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple would appear to have fixed the issue. I was facing the same issue but this morning I can submit the new versions for external testing review.