# External Testers in iTunes Connect always remains 'Inactive' when having 'TestFlight Beta Testing' turned on... How do I fix this issue?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

**For this App, the first time that I uploaded the binary the 'External' column correctly presented the action 'Submit for Beta App Review'...**

**After clicking on it, the App got successfully reviewed...**

**After that, I sent another binary for a new version and now the column 'External' remains Inactive...**

**PS.: I have added external users(the status remains 'Added') and I have also filled in all information in 'Build Details'.
Other Apps in my account are working correctly, only this one has this issue.**

*How do I fix this? Is it a known issue in iTunes Beta Testing?*

Any help or guidance is really appreciated... Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: This problem still exists now WTF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple have fixed the issue, my 1.1 version had the same issue but the submit for review button is now available again.

Comment: Yes, they fixed the issue yesterday. That's great! Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I asked apple developer center, and they confirmed it is true that external beta test can only be used for the first time currently.